# Best practices of including javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html

I've been reading in many places and also used the knowledge to good effect about including javascript at the bottom of the page unless there are some document.write scripts or scoping issues. But recently, I came across something I've never(probably) seen or used. Some people use the script tag inside an 'i' tag. I don't know the reason of using script tags inside some other tag.

I'd really appreciate clarifications to my question.

p.s. The 'i' tag which has all the script tags is at the bottom of the page, just before the closing body tag.

Comment: Any examples of that?

Comment: If you viewed the rendered page w/ scripting enabled through a dom inspector, was there anything within the italics tag?

Comment: @Hanky I saw Notyfy using it.

Comment: @ItzWarty I disabled JavaScript and tried. The 'i' tag has the script tags as they are written.

Comment: @RupamDatta if you view the source you will see that the 'i' tags are not there as they are getting created at a later point in the dom. Absolutely no reason for putting your script tags in an 'i' tag

Comment: I think the notyfy developer has some obsession with italics, check out the site http://craga89.github.io/notyfy/, it's ALL ITALICS (oh my eyes..). Yeah, back to topic, there shouldn't be any reason put them inside `i`.

Comment: @RupamDatta: no, they don't use it. They just use invalid html where they do not close all tags properly. That produces this effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're talking about http://craga89.github.io/notyfy/ and you're seeing the `<i>` tag in Firebug's HTML panel or a similar tool:

[image: Firebug - HTML pane]

That page contains [invalid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://craga89.github.io/notyfy/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). Particularly, it has several unclosed tags. That makes the browser apply certain fixes before rendering the page, since it needs to work with valid HTML in order to generate a DOM tree in memory. The main problem with that is that there's no guarantee that all browsers will generate the same fixes or that those fixes will work as intended.

If you open the original HTML code (in some browsers you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) you'll see that `<script>` tags are not surrounded by a `<i>` tag. What you see in the DOM node is the result of the fixes applied by the browser.

For instance, there's an unclosed `<i>` tag on top:

```
<i>notyfy adds the ability to style notyfy via CSS, as well removing the need for JS-based layouts and implementing event-type callbacks.</p>
```

And in case you wonder, some front-end frameworks such as Twitter Boostrap have decided to (ab)use the `<i>` tag to display icons:

```
<span class="runner" data-layout="top" data-type="alert">Alert <i class="icon-caret-right"></i></span>
```

Of course, this has nothing to do with JavaScript—such icons are generated with CSS.

---

**Edit:** There's a subtle but important difference between HTML code and DOM tree. The browser uses the HTML code to build a memory representation of the document that's called DOM tree. HTML is designed to be potentially invalid but the DOM tree cannot. For instance, this HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Invalid HTML test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hellow, <i>world</div>
</body>
</html>
```

... will generate this tree:

[image: Firebug's HTML panel]

As you can see, they are different. In order to generate a valid document structure, my browser has completely removed the `<div>` tag and has decided to close the `<p>` and `<i>` tags right before the body end.

Comment: @MrLister I normally take comments from 10k users seriously but I have the impression that you don't know the difference between HTML code and DOM tree. I'll update my answer for you.

Comment: I do actually. If you look at "Page Info" with Firefox, you will see that the page is rendered in standard compliance mode. Also, you are mixing up tags and elements.

Comment: @MrLister - Of course, quirks mode is a term that applies to a specific scenario we don't have here. I've removed it from the answer.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario This is a fantastic explanation by you. Now I'm in the notion that wrapping the script actually doesnot make any good to the site developed.

Comment: @RupamDatta - To be precise, wrapping the script is not intentional.